# Move Point - Centroid

Tags: java, methods, move

The purpose of the method is to take in a Point (c), then move the current centroid (x,y) to the new coordinated provided. This is done through finding the difference of the two and then translating the point to the new coordinate. However, I do not know how to set the new centroid value since I am setting the methods as voids.... Any ideas?
Sorry for all of the code, tried to put as little as possible. Translate takes the point(x,y) and adds the values given (dx,dy).

```
private Point centroid;
Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

    triPoints = new Point[] { a, b, c };

}

public Point getCentroid() {
Point centroid;
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    x = (a.getX() + b.getX() + c.getX()) / 3;
    y = (a.getY() + b.getY() + c.getY()) / 3;

    centroid = new Point(x, y);

    return centroid;
}

 public void move(double dx, double dy) {

     centroid = getCentroid();


     System.out.println(centroid.getX() + " "+ centroid.getY());
centroid = centroid.translate(dx, dy);
Point newCentroid =  new Point(centroid.getX(),centroid.getY());
 System.out.println(newCentroid.getX() + "  "+ newCentroid.getY());
if(getCentroid().equals(newCentroid)){

}else{

}
    for (int index = 0; index < triPoints.length - 1; index++) {

        triPoints[index].translate(dx, dy);


    }

}


 public void move(Point c) {



    double firstx = 0.0;
    double firsty = 0.0;

    Point f = getCentroid();
 System.out.println(f.getX()+ " "+ f.getY() + " "+ c.getX()+ " "+ c.getY());
    if (f.getX() >= c.getX()) {
firstx = c.getX() - f.getX();}
        else{
firstx = Math.abs(f.getX() - c.getX());
    }
    if (f.getY()>= c.getY()){
        firsty = c.getY() - f.getY();
    }
     else {
        firsty = Math.abs(f.getY() -c.getY());
    }




    move(firstx, firsty);

//System.out.println(centroid.getX() + " " + centroid.getY());

}
```

Comment: Currently it is just returning my centroid values  and not establishing the new Point

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using java.awt.Point?

If so, centroid.translate(dx, dy) is a void method: no value is actually returned, so

```
    centroid =centroid.translate(dx, dy)
```

does not actually do anything.

Since you are just wanting a new centroid, try doing

```
     centroid = getCentroid();
     System.out.println(centroid.getX() + " "+ centroid.getY());
     Point newCentroid =  new Point(centroid.getX() + dx,centroid.getY() + dy);
     System.out.println(newCentroid.getX() + "  "+ newCentroid.getY());
```

There is no need to do the translate if all you want to do once you translate is make a new centroid.

Also, neither the translate function nor the constructor take a double (which makes sense if you are on a standard x,y graph), so you can make dx and dy int.

Comment: That does set it to the right value, but it wont let me grab that value if I call upon getCentroid()... how do I accomplish this?

Comment: So once you create the new centroid, you want to retrieve it with getCentroid()? I am assuming that a, b, and c are declared as Point in the class, as well as triPoints being declared as Point[] in the class. You need to fix your loop -- don't need to subtract 1 from the length of the array ----

for (int index = 0; index < triPoints.length; index++) {
triPoints[index].translate(dx, dy);
}